# Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense starts in bootloader mode on power up

Tags: serial, arduino-nano-ble

I'm facing a lot of issues with Arduino Nano BLE Sense.
I'm aware about the port switching between bootloader (when the yellow LED pulses) and application.

**First issue**
Sometime when I power up the board (i.e. pluggin in the USB cable or turn on the PC) it starts in bootloader mode, even if there's a working sketch inside.
This is very bad, because I didn't find a way to recover from this situation without pressing the reset button, and of course this is not doable in a real environment.

**Second issue**
Even when it starts the application and I can successfully open the serial port, it does not receive or send any data. To recover, again, I need to press the reset button. The sketch is very simple and I also tried with default examples. Anyway, here how I open the serial port i Arduino:

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);
  Serial.flush();
}
```

Please note, that once it starts in the correct way it works without any problem!

Questions:

1. is there a way to software reset the board to force the application to start when in bootloader mode? I tried with `ard-reset-arduino.py --caterina /dev/ttyACM1` with no luck (i.e. it remains in bootloader mode).
2. do you have any suggestion how to avoid the serial issues I'm facing? I tried with several Arduino boards (I have 10 on my desk) and 3 different PCs.

Comment: Are you sure it's in bootloader mode and not just waiting for that `while(!Serial)` to become true? That will never happen until you open the serial port from the PC.

Comment: @PMF, even if I don't open the port on PC side usually the yellow LED is off (application mode). Sometimes instead it pulses on power up. Resetting the board leads to turn off the LED. Furthermore, when the LED pulses I can upload the firmware but I cannot exchange serial data with my application. When the LED is off I can (unless issue #2).

Comment: So, yes, I'm pretty sure it's in bootloader mode for issue #1.